# How to overwrite (save) a file when it has been edited?

Tags: java, file

I am currently developing a small data management application and would like to have another "Save" entry besides the existing "Save as -> XML / CSV" menu items.

This entry should overwrite the last loaded file with the changed data without opening a dialog again (like in MS Excel or Word).

Of course I have already done some research, but didn't find anything suitable or searched for the wrong one.

**These entries and functions I already have and they work:**

```
MenuItem saveXML = new MenuItem("Save as XML");
saveXML.setOnAction((e) -> {
// save file as XML
});

MenuItem saveCSV = new MenuItem("Save as CSV");
saveCSV.setOnAction((e) -> {
// save file as CSV
});
```

**I would like to create this entry:**

```
MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
saveCSV.setOnAction((e) -> {
// Save the last opened document in the same format (XML or CSV) without any dialog
});
```

[This is my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQgUf.png)

Comment: You need to use some shared state (like a global variable) that you assign to to keep track of what the last action was. This global state would be assigned to by saveXML.setOnAction lambda and saveCSV.setOnAction lambda. Then when the user clicks on "save", the handler should use this glboal state to determine how to save the file.

Comment: So if you loaded an XML file, you want to save it as XML when the user selects the _Save_ menu item, right? Same for CSV file?

Comment: @Abra Yes, exactly.

Comment: this is unrelated to fx, just plain java - please work through a tutorial on basic language features and file handling. That said: there is no automatism, it's you who needs to implement the conversion from one format to another (or use external support libraries)

Comment: @kleopatrA You may be right that it is only about Java and not about Javafx. But I think it's presumptuous to suggest that I should learn basic language futures. I think in this case it's more about the fact that I didn't come up with the solution and not that I don't understand how to implement a solution. Amen

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that looks like you did try any content formatting ..

Comment: New members should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Here is a quote from that Web page: _This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat._

Comment: I see from the screen capture of your app that you linked to in your question, that you have a _Load_ [menu] item. When the user loads a file, you need to save, in some variable, whether it was a XML file or a CSV file. Then when the user selects the _Save_ menu item, you check the value of that variable in order to know what kind of file you need to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abra suggested, you must remember the location of the most recently loaded file by storing it in a private field:

```
private File currentFile;
```

Then you set it whenever you load a file:

```
MenuItem load = new MenuItem("Load");
load.setOnAction(e -> {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    // (set FileChooser's title and filters here)
    File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    if (file != null) {
        // (load file into application)
        this.currentFile = file;
    }
});
```

Now, you can use that `currentFile` value to save:

```
MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
save.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (currentFile != null) {
        // (write to currentFile)
    } else {
        // New file;  ask user for save location.

        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        // (set FileChooser's title and filters here)
        File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
        if (file != null) {
            // (save file as CSV or XML depending on chosen filter)
            this.currentFile = file;
        }
    }
});
```

You may want to move your save logic into private methods, if you haven’t already.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I have already found a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works for me. It may not be the optimal solution, but it could still be useful.

I pass a property to my menuItem that contains the path of my file **.put("FILE_LOCATION",..)** and use this property in the save-event to select the last path.

Since I also want to save automatically as either CSV or XML file, I delete the path from the variable that contains the other one, if it exists. **.remove("FILE_LOCATION")**

```
loadCSV.setOnAction(e -> {
        ...
        File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        loadCSV.getProperties().put("FILE_LOCATION", f.getAbsolutePath());
        loadXML.getProperties().remove("FILE_LOCATION");
});
```

Then I check which variable is filled and then run the respective method.

```
save.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            if (loadCSV.getProperties().isEmpty() == false) {
                File saveCSV = new File(loadCSV.getProperties().get("FILE_LOCATION").toString());
                if (saveCSV != null) {
                    CSV.writeCSV(saveCSV, DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist());
                }
            } else if (loadXML.getProperties().isEmpty() == false) {
                File saveXML = new File(loadXML.getProperties().get("FILE_LOCATION").toString());
                if (saveXML != null) {
                    XML.writeXMLList(saveXML, DataHandler.INSTANCE.foodlist());
                }
            }
    });
```